# Issue with DOM element GetElementByTagName in PHP

Tags: php, dom, getelementsbytagname

```
<FlightSegment DepartureDateTime="2016-09-20T06:05:00" ArrivalDateTime="2016-09-20T08:05:00" FlightNumber="716" ResBookDesigCode="N">
    <FlightDuration>2016-09-14T02:00:00</FlightDuration>
    <DepartureAirport LocationCode="IST" Terminal="I" />
    <ArrivalAirport LocationCode="KBP" />
    <OperatingAirline Code="PS" />
    <Equipment AirEquipType="73H" />
    <MarketingAirline Code="PS" />
    <BookingClassAvails>
        <BookingClassAvail ResBookDesigCode="N" ResBookDesigQuantity="9" RPH="ADT" AvailablePTC="ADT" ResBookDesigCabinCode="M" FareBasis="NL1LTP4" />
    </BookingClassAvails>
</FlightSegment>
<FlightSegment DepartureDateTime="2016-09-20T09:50:00" ArrivalDateTime="2016-09-20T11:55:00" FlightNumber="101" ResBookDesigCode="N">
    <FlightDuration>2016-09-14T03:05:00</FlightDuration>
    <DepartureAirport LocationCode="KBP" />
    <ArrivalAirport LocationCode="AMS" />
    <OperatingAirline Code="PS" />
    <Equipment AirEquipType="73R" />
    <MarketingAirline Code="PS" />
    <BookingClassAvails>
        <BookingClassAvail ResBookDesigCode="N" ResBookDesigQuantity="9" RPH="ADT" AvailablePTC="ADT" ResBookDesigCabinCode="M" FareBasis="NL1LTP4" />
    </BookingClassAvails>
</FlightSegment>
```

There are two Flight Segments.
We don`t have any identificators in this code, so,

1. How could I divide this code by blocks to use attributes from first `<FlightSegment>` block?
2. Also I need to count `<FlightSegments>`.

Please HELP! )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this function to convert an XML node to a (nested) array:

```
function domToArray($node) {
    $arr = [];
    // Add all attributes of this node as key/values:
    foreach ($node->attributes as $attribute) {
        $arr[$attribute->nodeName] = $attribute->nodeValue;
    }
    // Iterate through the child nodes
    foreach ($node->childNodes as $child) {
        if ($child->nodeType === XML_TEXT_NODE) {
            // Assign the text content to a "value" key
            if (trim($child->textContent)!== '') {
                $arr['value'] = $child->textContent;
            }
        } else if ($child->nodeType === XML_ELEMENT_NODE) {
            // Create key/value pairs for child nodes, using recursion.
            // If the children are repeated elements, then build
            // an indexed array, otherwise an associative array.
            if (preg_replace("/y$/", "ie", $child->nodeName) ."s" === $node->nodeName) {
                $arr[] = domToArray($child);
            } else {
                $arr[$child->nodeName] = domToArray($child);
            }
        }
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

You would first have to create a `DOMDocument` and read the XML string into it. Note that the piece of XML you provided needs to be wrapped in a single element, which I have called `FlightSegments` on purpose -- the multiple of `FlightSegment` of which you have 2:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML("<FlightSegments>$xml</FlightSegments>");
```

Once you have that, you can call the function I mentioned above:

```
// Convert XML to nested array:
$flightSegments = domToArray($doc->documentElement);
```

Here is some of the output you can get from that array:

```
// Number of FlightSegments:
echo "Number of FlightSegment elements: " . count($flightSegments) . "<br>";

echo "DepartureDateTime of first FlightSegment: " . $flightSegments[0]['DepartureDateTime'] . "<br>";

echo "All information:<br>";

print_r ($flightSegments);
```

See it run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/643663).

With the sample XML you provided, the output of the above code would be:

```
Number of FlightSegment elements: 2
DepartureDateTime of first FlightSegment: 2016-09-20T06:05:00
All information:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [DepartureDateTime] => 2016-09-20T06:05:00
            [ArrivalDateTime] => 2016-09-20T08:05:00
            [FlightNumber] => 716
            [ResBookDesigCode] => N
            [FlightDuration] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 2016-09-14T02:00:00
                )

            [DepartureAirport] => Array
                (
                    [LocationCode] => IST
                    [Terminal] => I
                )

            [ArrivalAirport] => Array
                (
                    [LocationCode] => KBP
                )

            [OperatingAirline] => Array
                (
                    [Code] => PS
                )

            [Equipment] => Array
                (
                    [AirEquipType] => 73H
                )

            [MarketingAirline] => Array
                (
                    [Code] => PS
                )

            [BookingClassAvails] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [ResBookDesigCode] => N
                            [ResBookDesigQuantity] => 9
                            [RPH] => ADT
                            [AvailablePTC] => ADT
                            [ResBookDesigCabinCode] => M
                            [FareBasis] => NL1LTP4
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [DepartureDateTime] => 2016-09-20T09:50:00
            [ArrivalDateTime] => 2016-09-20T11:55:00
            [FlightNumber] => 101
            [ResBookDesigCode] => N
            [FlightDuration] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 2016-09-14T03:05:00
                )

            [DepartureAirport] => Array
                (
                    [LocationCode] => KBP
                )

            [ArrivalAirport] => Array
                (
                    [LocationCode] => AMS
                )

            [OperatingAirline] => Array
                (
                    [Code] => PS
                )

            [Equipment] => Array
                (
                    [AirEquipType] => 73R
                )

            [MarketingAirline] => Array
                (
                    [Code] => PS
                )

            [BookingClassAvails] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [ResBookDesigCode] => N
                            [ResBookDesigQuantity] => 9
                            [RPH] => ADT
                            [AvailablePTC] => ADT
                            [ResBookDesigCabinCode] => M
                            [FareBasis] => NL1LTP4
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

#### Edit after you provided complete XML

I am not sure what your problem is any more, because in comments you shared code where you walk through your XML successfully.

Just to note that you can use the above function to turn the complete XML into an array (I made one correction to the function to correctly identify the plural of a tag name that ends with "y").

Here is how you would call it on your XML:

```
$soap = domToArray($xmlDoc->documentElement);
```

The content of `$soap` would be (I truncated it):

```
Array
(
    [soap:Body] => Array
        (
            [SearchFlightResponse] => Array
                (
                    [OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS] => Array
                        (
                            [Version] => 0
                            [HasMoreResult] => Array
                                (
                                    [value] => false
                                )

                            [Success] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [PricedItineraries] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [Currency] => USD
                                            [ProviderType] => AmadeusProvider
                                            [SequenceNumber] => 0
                                            [AirItinerary] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [OriginDestinationOptions] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [RefNumber] => 0
                                                                    [DirectionId] => 0
                                                                    [ElapsedTime] => 0650
                                                                    [FlightSegment] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [DepartureDateTime] => 2016-09-20T09:50:00
                                                                            [ArrivalDateTime] => 2016-09-20T11:55:00
                                                                            [FlightNumber] => 101
                                                                            [ResBookDesigCode] => N
                                                                            [FlightDuration] => Array
                                                                                (
                                                                                    [value] => 2016-09-14T03:05:00
                                                                                )

                                                                            [DepartureAirport] => Array
                                                                                (
                                                                                    [LocationCode] => KBP
                                                                                )

                                                                            [ArrivalAirport] => Array
                                                                                (
                                                                                    [LocationCode] => AMS
                                                                                )

                                                                            [OperatingAirline] => Array
                                                                                (
                                                                                    [Code] => PS
                                                                                )

                                                                            [Equipment] => Array
                                                                                (
                                                                                    [AirEquipType] => 73R
                                                                                )

                                                                            [MarketingAirline] => Array
                                                                                (
                                                                                    [Code] => PS
                                                                                )

                                                                            [BookingClassAvails] => Array
                                                                                (
                                                                                    [0] => Array
                                                                                        (
                                                                                            [ResBookDesigCode] => N
                                                                                            [ResBookDesigQuantity] => 9
                                                                                            [RPH] => ADT
                                                                                            [AvailablePTC] => ADT
                                                                                            [ResBookDesigCabinCode] => M
                                                                                            [FareBasis] => NL1LTP4
                                                                                        )

                                                                                )
```

Now you can write code like:

```
$itineries = $soap['soap:Body']['SearchFlightResponse']['OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS']['PricedItineraries']; 
foreach ($itineries as $itinery) {
    // ... etc. Always array access.
}
```

Comment: thanks for help. But how i can use this:
$flightSegments = domToArray($doc->documentElement);

In my code:
$ticketsflightsegment = $refnumbers->getElementsByTagName("FlightSegment");

Comment: This is my full code https://eval.in/643821

And this is fuck.xml https://eval.in/643822

Comment: It seems you already wrote the code to walk through the XML with DOM methods, so now I really don't get what the problem is. If you only want the first FlightSegment, and not both, then `break` out of the `foreach` loop after the first...

Comment: Ok, I trying myself to solve in my issue. So you can help me:
What is `$node` in your function?

Comment: `$node` is any element in your XML. When coming in as argument, it is the node I had added myself (`FlightSegments`), but as the function is called recursively, it will be the nested elements one at a time (`FlightSegment`, `FlightDuration` ... etc). The function is intended to get rid of the DOM functions, and be able to access your data in a more friendly array structure. Now that you have given your complete XML, it could be modified to also work with that.

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach().??
I have `$ticketsflightsegment = $refnumbers->getElementsByTagName("FlightSegment");` and i put `$ticketsflightsegment` instead of `$node`

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot help you like this. Have you debugged? Which `foreach`? which variable? What have you passed to the function?

Comment: `$ticketsflightsegment = domToArray($refnumbers->getElementsByTagName("FlightSegment"));
                                                            echo "Number of FlightSegment elements: " . count($ticketsflightsegment) . "\n";`

Comment: The function is not designed to pass a node list to. You need to provide it a single node. I updated my answer, showing how you could turn your whole XML to a nested array. It might be easier to work with that, and do your `foreach` loops on that, and take a `count` where needed.

Comment: Trincot thanks for you big help me. I trying myself to solve in my issue with you solve code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

now your function creates the massive from the last segment of xml document:

```
<?php

function domToArray($node) {
    $arr = [];
    // Add all attributes of this node as key/values:
    foreach ($node->attributes as $attribute) {
        $arr[$attribute->nodeName] = $attribute->nodeValue;
    }
    $useName = true;
    // Iterate through the child nodes
    foreach ($node->childNodes as $child) {
        if ($child->nodeType === XML_TEXT_NODE) {
            // Assign the text content to a "value" key
            if (trim($child->textContent)!== '') {
                $arr['value'] = $child->textContent;
            }
        } else if ($child->nodeType === XML_ELEMENT_NODE) {
            // Create key/value pairs for child nodes, using recursion.
            // If the children are repeated elements, then build
            // an indexed array, otherwise an associative array.
            if ($child->nodeName ."s" === $node->nodeName) {
                $arr[] = domToArray($child);
            } else {
                $arr[$child->nodeName] = domToArray($child);
            }
        }
    }
    return $arr;
}





$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load("response.xml");
$soap = domToArray($xmlDoc->documentElement);
print_r($soap);

?>
```

Here you can see all document entirely: [response.xml](https://eval.in/644273)

And here is what contains `$soap`: [Array](https://eval.in/644275)

Your decision was ideal:

```
// If the children are repeated elements, then build
// an indexed array, otherwise an associative array.
```

...but is doesn't build an indexed array when I'm trying to load an response.xml. It just build massive with last FlightSegment...

P.S. I`m not same person, we just working together. )